# APNS without Badge/Alert/Sound

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

Can I send a notification to APNS without Badge / Alert / Sound, which should notify only to my app which is installed in the iPhone ?

It's like custom notification sending via APNS to the App in the device which should not alert the user.

Is it possible,if yes how ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: not getting your point..

Comment: @Sarah : I need  to send a push notification to my App in the device. That push notification should not contain Badge or Alert or Sound. Is that possible ? Am i clear now ?

Comment: APNS use to be in form of these 3. If you don't want to sent in that manner,what do you want to send?

Comment: I want to send notification from the server to my mobile client app in the device . I dont want to notify the client , but i need to push some data or message to the app .

Comment: some data or message can be in form of alert,badges or sound only.

Comment: Push Notifications are not guaranteed to reach your App. You would be better to have your app check your server for new information everytime the app starts up (application didBecomeActive).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heh. It could be done (but I don't understand the purpose of that):

1) Ask user if he wants to receive Push-notifications that contains only *sound* alert

2) Send Push-notification without text and set sound-file that doesn't exists in app bundle or that is silent, for example:

```
{
    "aps" : {
         "sound" : "0.aiff"
    }
}
```

Do you understand my hack? =)

Comment: Thanks for the Reply . Yes i can get you. But i dont want to alert the user by any means. Its just like MDM server waking up the device without the user alert. Like that, i need to send some data or message to the app without alert. help me

Comment: So if your sound will be missed or it will be silence then user won't be informed.... But your app will receive such push only if it is active.

Comment: Active ? You mean the App should keep on running ? ok, If my app is running(always), how that can be achieved ? Thnks

Comment: Nekto If the App is inactive when the silent, invisible PN arrives then wouldn't the App receive the PN the next time the App is active?